# How to avoid that 0 (zero) int turns into Postgres "null" value and violates "not null" constraint?

Tags: postgresql, go, sql-null

In Go, I am unmarshalling/decoding JSON into a struct with an ID field of type int. Then I try to insert this struct into a PostgreSQL database using go-pg with the ID column as the primary key (which has a not-null constraint). The first entry has a `0` as its ID. In the Postgres documentation, it states that `0` is ok as a value of a primary key. However, I keep getting an error message:

> "ERROR #23502 null value in column "number" violates not-null constraint".

It looks like the `0` turns into a Go "zero value" when it is unmarshalled into the int value. Then it is inserted as `null` value into Postgres. Any tips on how I might be able to avoid this would be greatly appreciated.

```
type Account struct {
   Number int `sql:"type:smallint, pk"`
   Name string
}

[...]

account := Account{}
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&account)

[...]

insertErr := pgLayer.db.Insert(&account)
if insertErr != nil {
   log.Printf("Error while inserting new item")
   return "n/a", insertErr
}
```

Comment: Did you try `sql:"smallint,pk,notnull"` ?

Answer (score 2):

While it's not immediately obvious with `go-pg` you can use the struct tag `sql:",notnull"` to show that Go empty values (`""`, `0`, `[]` etc.) are allowed and should not be treated as SQL `NULL`.

You can see it in the [Features list](https://github.com/go-pg/pg#features).

In your case I would change this to:

```golang
type Account struct {
   Number int `sql:"type:smallint,pk,notnull"`
   Name string
}
```

Comment: These are the things we should avoid when writing libraries. This ends up imposing a specific coding style. In any other language, a 0 is just a zero and doesn't get interpreted as NULL.

Comment: Since v9 you should use `pg:",use_zero"` to achieve the same.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest solution to your problem is to make your `ID` column of type `SERIAL` and let Postgres deal with setting and auto-incrementing the value for you. If you need the value within your application directly after inserting it, you can always use a `RETURNING` psql clause, like such:

```sql
INSERT INTO shows(
    user_id, name, description, created, modified
) VALUES(
    :user_id, :name, :created, :modified
) RETURNING id;
```

And capture the response within your code.